# how to add raster data using mapbox gl js?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add a Cloud Optimized Geotiff raster layer on map, data is in AWS s3 bucket.
How to overlay my raster data on mapbox gl js?
Is it correct to fetch the object url of s3?
if you know how to do this please answer me..

```
map.on('load', function(){
  map.addSource('cog-data', {
    "type": "raster",
    "tiles": ["data url"],
    "tileSize": 256
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "cog-data",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": "cog-data",
    "minzoom": 0,
    "maxzoom": 22,
    'layout': {
      'visibility': 'visible'
    },
  });
```

Comment: What you're doing looks correct. What is the form of the `["data url"],` bit? If you don't want to share the full URL, just replace part of it, so we can see that the overall structure looks right. What is actually going wrong anyway?

Comment: Thank you @SteveBennett. Part of `["data url"]` is `["https://s3-bucket.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/filename.tif"]`. Is it correct to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a `raster` source, the source data needs to be tiled. In that case, the URL would be something like `.../{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

Since you apparently have a single TIF that covers the whole area, you should use an `image` source instead:

```
  map.addSource('cog-data', {
    "type": "image",
    "url": "...tif",
    "coordinates": [...]

  });
```

I'm not certain that this works, but hopefully it does.

Documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#image

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not working. I modified type, url and coordinates. The example in documentation works well. If I replace it with the url of s3, nothing overlays. Is this problem with s3 url?

Comment: As far as I know, only JPG and GIF work for raster. Steve is usually on the money, so I would still trust his answer.

Comment: I put the sample data(radar.gif) of the document into s3 bucket. It does not work too

Comment: `"url":"https://test-bucket.s3.ap-northeaset-2.amazonaws.com/radar.gif"` Is this the correct url format?

Comment: Yes...if that's actually a publicly accessible URL. But as David suggested, I'm not sure what image formats are supported. Normally, PNG and JPEG are used. It doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: The reason for not being visualized was the CORS problem of S3. So I can mapping the image file in S3. but I want Tiff(COG) mapping too.
How do I create a raster source url??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.